# Calculate time delay between time series

Tags: r

I have two time series denoting cumulative counts at the entrance and exit of an area. The vertical distance between the series can be interpreted as the instantaneous occupancy of the area, and the horizontal distance is the average "dwell" time. The real data is at 1-minute resolution, with data in each minute with observations. (Sample data at bottom.)

What's a simple, readable, efficient way to calculate the horizontal time delay between the two series across the day? e.g at each point in series 2105, how many minutes to the (first) linearly-interpolated point on series 2081 with the same y value?

```
# using df1 defined at bottom
ggplot(df1, aes(datetime, cuml, color = label)) + 
  geom_line() +   
  geom_point()
```

[image]

One approach I thought about was to lerp each series using `dplyr::complete` + `zoo::na.approx`, then non-equi join each series to the others for the closest match, but that seems inefficient and unwieldy for my use case of ~20 sensors, 200 days @ 1-minute resolution. For example:

```
library(dplyr); library(zoo)
df1 %>%
  complete(label, datetime = seq.POSIXt(
    min(df1$datetime), max(df1$datetime), by = "min")) %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  mutate(cuml2 = na.spline(cuml, datetime)) %>%
  ungroup() -> df2

df2 %>% filter(label == "2105 Line 0-exit") %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% filter(label != "2105 Line 0-exit"), by = character()) %>%
  mutate(dif = cuml2.x - cuml2.y) %>%
  group_by(datetime.x) %>%
  slice_min(abs(dif), n = 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(time_dif = datetime.y - datetime.x)
```

Example data

```
df1 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1670152500, 1670152500, 
  1670154300, 1670156100, 1670156100, 1670157900, 1670157900, 1670159700, 
  1670159700, 1670161500, 1670161500, 1670163300, 1670163300, 1670165100, 
  1670165100, 1670166900, 1670166900, 1670168700, 1670168700, 1670170500, 
  1670170500, 1670172300, 1670172300, 1670174100, 1670174100, 1670175900, 
  1670175900), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    label = c("2081 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", 
    "2081 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", 
    "2105 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", 
    "2105 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", 
    "2105 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", 
    "2081 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", 
    "2081 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", 
    "2105 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit", 
    "2081 Line 0-exit", "2081 Line 0-exit", "2105 Line 0-exit"
    ), cuml = c(8.30121553513193, 96.9773299748111, 244.892247411139, 
    213.756300029647, 418.275958578226, 420.249036466054, 636.719843268962, 
    883.57122865939, 637.118292321376, 1137.27959697733, 891.343018084791, 
    1178.77260598873, 1388.04925832634, 1725.02099076406, 1407.05603320486, 
    1710.05040023718, 2025.74867058494, 2349.00643716765, 2043.13667358435, 
    2668.34592779177, 2346.13104061666, 2935.76826196474, 2649.12540764898, 
    3198.29275118948, 2988.43759264749, 3285.20604802846, 3421.63448082844
    )), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Does `df1 %>% pivot_wider(values_from=cuml, names_from=label) %>%  mutate(delta ='2105 Line 0-exit' - '2081 Line 0-exit')`  give you what you want? [Back ticks in code replaced by single quotes to aid formatting.]

Comment: No, that gives me the respective `cuml` values at each time; what I want is the respective times for each `cuml` values, ie x distance not y distance.

Comment: Ah! OK. I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data into a zoo object z splitting on the label column so that each series gets it own column.  That is, z now has 2 columns, one for each series.  Now use approxfun to get the time of the second column as a function of the second column value.  Look that up using the first column value and take the difference with the first column's time.  Average the differences.  The result is in seconds.  You may wish to reverse the terms of the difference depending on the direction of the result desired.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df1, split = "label")
mean(as.numeric(time(z)) - approxfun(z[, 2], time(z))(z[, 1]), na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 1712.595
```

Comment: Ooh, nice! So this lag is figuring the approx avg time since entry corresponding to each exit, and it looks like I can use `approxfun(z[, 1], time(z))(z[, 2]) - as.numeric(time(z))` to get the approx avg time until exit corresponding to each entry. Then I can `fortify.zoo(z,  names = c("datetime", "series", "value"), melt = TRUE)` to reshape for further analysis. Super!